# Calling one app from another app both having same package name in android

Tags: android, android-intent

1. hi friends i want to call one app from another app both are same package name please
   suggest something.

intent is used to call an activity but if both were same package means

```
                                  PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
              Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.package");
                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to install two apps with same package name in Android device.

If you do then it will ask you to update/replace already installed application having same package name.

Comment: when i am uploading two apk into google play it says you needs to change your package name to previously uploaded package name

Comment: Yes, that why I told you above, you have to take different package name of different apps which uniquely identify your app among other apps. It should be reverse domain name of your web.

Comment: @user2858029 The package name should only be the same for a new version of an app.  Different apps must have different package names.

Comment: ok i wiil tell my problem i uploaded on apk file in google play package name is com.layout.registration and i tried upload another apk for the same application and it package name is com.emergency.valert the first apk file will call the second apk using package manager class i mentioned above but Google play says you need to change you package name com.layout.registration if i change the package name of 2nd apk file then package manager class will get confuse because two apk file having the same package name rite?

Comment: No, you should not upload same apps two times with different package name if there is no change, you should take the same package name then release the update of your apps. If you take same package name then it will upload without any error and it will send the update notification to the users also who have currently your app installed

Comment: Ok, you can set an application with two different package name. But `Android` will process them as two different applications.

Comment: @user2858029 If Play will not let you upload an app with `com.layout.registration`, then an app with that package name already exists.  Just use a different package name.  But, the reason there is so much confusion is because you have not explained what you are trying to do.  "I tried to upload another APK for the same application" - you mean you are trying to upload a new version?  An update?

Comment: not a same app it is a plug-in of that app

Comment: it going to call second apk it contains another feature

Comment: Multiple apk each one has a seperate feature and everyone will be called by Main apk

Comment: then in this case you can put the plugin in the assets folder and then at run time you can copy the asset folder APK in to the SD card and then prompt user to install the plugin

Comment: @user2858029 So it's an expansion APK?  Or you are using an Intent filter?

Comment: yes it is a intent filter @Simon

Comment: what should i do please help i think you understood @Simon